# Apache Wicket AjaxRequestTarget ListView component not refreshing or updating

Tags: java, wicket-6

I am really new with apache wicket (Literally) and I got a task that needs refreshing a table(ListView) via ajax after adding an item (from bootstrap modal box).

Let's say I have a page display the laboratory details (room) and a table displaying the list of laboratory devices.

To add a laboratory device, there is a button that when clicked... will display a modal box (popup) where the use can select a laboratory devices from a dropdown.

When a laboratory device is added (from popup modal), the modal will be closed/hidden, then the table component will be refreshed via ajax.

**Problem:**

Code for refreshing the component `contentDevices` seems not working. After adding the laboratory device, I can see that it is reflected in the database.
But for unknown reasons, the container with table showing the list of laboratory devices is not refreshing.

I would like to refresh the container/component `contentDevices` after adding/removing laboratory device. The component `contentDevices` has a child which is a table that displays the list of devices in the laboratory.

The issue now is, I still need to refresh the page (browser refresh) inorder for the newly added laboratory device to reflect.

By the way, `Device` class does not have `onBeforeRender()`. The new instance of this class will replace the existing `contentDevices`.

It's been days already but I cannot figure out why it's not refreshing. This is really easy if this is just plain HTML/JS, but I am really clueless with apache wicket.

The page/html structure is something like this:

**Structure or Layout:**

```
<!-- HTML document -->
<Page>
  ...
    <!-- Content section -->
    <div id="content">
      <div id="detailsContainer">
        ...
      </div>
      <div id="devicesContainer">
        ...
        <div id="contentDevices">
          <!-- Other components (ex. table) here that needs to be refreshed after adding/removing device -->
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ...
</Page>
```

**Code:**

```
...

@Override
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
    super.onSubmit(target, form);

    laboratoryService.addDevice(this.laboratoryModel.getObject(), selectedDevice.getLabel(), selectedDevice.getValue());

    // Refresh laboratory model and update the list of laboratory devices from DB
    Laboratory laboratory = laboratoryService.getLaboratory(this.laboratoryModel.getObject().getId());
    this.laboratoryModel = new Model<>(laboratory);

    // Start: refreshing `contentDevices`
    WebMarkupContainer cContent = (WebMarkupContainer) getPage().get("content");
    WebMarkupContainer devicesContainer = (WebMarkupContainer) cContent.get("devicesContainer");
    Component cDevices = devicesContainer.get("contentDevices");
    cDevices.replaceWith(new Device("contentDevices", getMyPageContext(), this.laboratoryModel));

    devicesContainer.addOrReplace(cDevices);
    cContent.addOrReplace(devicesContainer);

    target.add(cContent);
    // End refreshing `contentDevices`

    // Hide bootstrap modal box
    MyUtil.hideBootstrapModalBox(target, "[data-locator=addDeviceModalBox]");

    // showCustomAlert - show success message
    target.appendJavaScript("showCustomAlert('success', 'Added laboratory device.', true);");
}

...
```

**Device class:**

```
public class Device extends AbstractMyPagePanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private LaboratoryService laboratoryService;

    private IModel<Laboratory> laboratoryModel;


    public Device(String id, MyPageContext myPageContext, IModel<Laboratory> laboratoryModel) {
        // `laboratoryModel` is passed until most parent class which is `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel`
        super(id, myPageContext, laboratoryModel);

        this.laboratoryModel = laboratoryModel;

        add(createAddDeviceButton());
        add(new AddDeviceModalBox("addDeviceModalBox", myPageContext, this.laboratoryModel));
        add(createRowsContainer());
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
    }

    private Component createAddDeviceButton() {
        return new WebMarkupContainer("addDeviceButton") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void onConfigure() {
                super.onConfigure();
                setVisible(isAdmin());
            }
        };
    }

    private Component createRowsContainer() {
        WebMarkupContainer result = new WebMarkupContainer("rowsContainer") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void onConfigure() {
                super.onConfigure();
                setVisible(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(this.laboratoryModel.getObject().getRoomDevices()));
                setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
            }
        };

        // This part here is OK, laboratory model and devices are updated
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("CREATE-ROW-CONTAINER");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("[device-count]: " + this.laboratoryModel.getObject().getRoomDevices().size());
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("LABORATORY-DEVICES");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        for (LaboratoryDevice device : this.laboratoryModel.getObject().getRoomDevices()) {
            System.out.println("[device]: " + device.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n");

        // This part here is not OK, `populateItem()` is not called
        // `rows.children` is null, but `rows.data.transientModelObject` is updated and contains the latest added laboratory device
        // Same goes when `add` is used instead of `addOrReplace`, the issue is still there
        result.addOrReplace(new ListView<LaboratoryDevice>("rows", this.laboratoryModel.getObject().getRoomDevices()) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<LaboratoryDevice> item) {
                LaboratoryDevice device = item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("name", device.getName()));
                item.add(new Label("sn", device.getSn()));
                item.add(new WebMarkupContainer("removeButton").setVisible(isAdmin()));
                item.add(new RemoveLaboratoryDeviceModalBox("removeLaboratoryDeviceModalBox",
                                                  getMyPageContext(), item.getModel()));
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

}
```

I know this is very basic but I could not find anything the really works in the net :(

Thanks!

Comment: Seems the issue here is ListView is not updating/refreshing. Even when `laboratoryDevicesModel` contains the most latest data... it does not call `populateItem()`... I believe that I missed or misused something that is why `populateItem()` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether there are any errors:

- errors in the server logs
- errors in the browser's Dev Tools Console

I guess there is an JS error in the Dev Tools saying that Wicket cannot find an HTML element with id `contentXYZ`. If this is the case then make sure you call `cContent.setOutputMarkupId(true)` where `cContent` is instantiated, i.e. in the constructor of the page.

You do not need `cDevices.setOutputMarkupId(true)` because you never add `cDevices` to the `target`.

And calling `setOutputMarkupId(true)` in `onXYZ(AjaxRequestTarget)` most of the time is too late because the whole page is already rendered and the component/element needs to render an `id` attribute which will be used later when the Ajax response tries to find the old HTML element and replace it with the new one (created or updated in `onXYZ(AjaxRequestTarget)`.

Comment: I checked the browser's dev tool and server log, but there was no error. However, when I debugged... `result.addOrReplace(new ListView<LaboratoryDevice>("rows", this.laboratoryDevicesModel) { ... });` the children is null which I think should not be. it does not go inside `populateItem()` maybe because `children = null`

Comment: Also, data `transientModelObject` is correct and contains the updated data and I can see the latest laboratory device added. but this was not reflected in the actual table (UI)

Comment: not sure why `rows` component (ListView) is not updated even when the data is updated.